# Converting multiline string to vector of integers

Tags: rust

What would be the best way to convert multiline string which also contains spaces to a vector of integers so calculations can be made after based on their indexes.

```
fn main() {

    let x = String::from("123 
    456 
    789");

    let nums: Vec<char> = x.chars().collect();
    println!("{:?}", nums);
}
```

I have a vector which contains characters, what would be the best way to make a new vector out of it with only digits.

Desired result would be: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is not an exact duplicate – it's about parsing the string into the vector `[123, 456, 789]` rather than parsing each digit into its own number.  The result desired here is rather unusual – you could use `let nums: Vec<i32> = x.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_string().parse().ok()).collect();`.

Comment: True, it was not exact duplicate but it gave I hint to use filter_map. I used  ´let nums: Vec<i32> = x
        .filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok())
        .collect(); ´but your answer is also correct. Thank you